# Could current approach for calling File2.ps1 in Maindir by running File1.ps1 in Subdir using Powershell be more concise?

Tags: powershell

**Directory structure**

```
path\to\folder1\file1.ps1
path\to\file2.ps1
```

*file1.ps1:*

```
. (Join-Path (Split-Path -Parent (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition))  'file2.ps1')
```

*file.ps2:*

```
Write-Host "Helloworld!"
```

**Outcome**

```
path\to\folder1> .\file1.ps1
Helloworld!
```

Comment: Do you mean `. ..\file2.ps1`?

Comment: My point was that `..\file2.ps1` is equivalent to `(Join-Path (Split-Path -Parent (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition))  'file2.ps1')`.

Comment: I have changed it to `. ..\file2.ps1` and the outcome is identical. Thank you. This answers the question.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Perhaps you could post the comment as an answer, as it answers the question.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Due to the comment of Markz the question has been reviewed and updated. The file1.ps1 needs to call file2.ps1.

Comment: @utrecht Honestly these edits are making the question less clear. I will only add that as of Powershell 3, the variable `$PSScriptRoot` is automatically defined to be the directory containing the currently executing script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
. ..\file2.ps1
```

instead, because it is equivalent to

```
. (Join-Path (Split-Path -Parent (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)) 'file2.ps1')
```

if the current location is a subdirectory of the location of file2.ps1.

If you need to run file2.ps1 from the parent directory of the currently running script (regardless of current location), you can write:

```
. join-path (split-path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -parent) "..\file2.ps1"
```

Comment: Those two are slightly different. The first runs a script in the parent directory of the current path provider location. The second runs a script in the parent directory of the currently executing script.